Where from the standard do I read that exceptions of derived class held by base class reference are sliced when caught?
Consider this code:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <exception>

void foo(std::exception const& e1) {
    try {
        std::cout << e1.what() << std::endl;
        throw e1;
    } catch (std::exception const& e2) {
        std::cout << e2.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    foo(std::runtime_error{"this is not std::exception"});
}

It will print the following
this is not std::exception
std::exception

where the second line, if I understand correctly, is not mandated by the standard.
Anyway, the code from which I distilled the snippet above is how I discovered that, despite in throw e1; e1 is an object of derived class (even though held via a base class reference), it gets sliced before reaching the handler.
What part of the standard tells me this is the expected behavior?
I think this sentence is probably relevant:

The exception object is copy-initialized ([dcl.init.general]) from the (possibly converted) operand.

Does is copy-initialized mean that the "entity" bound to e in the catch line is initialized like this
auto entityToWhich_e2_isBound = e1;

instead of like this?
auto& entityToWhich_e2_isBound = e1;

If I follow the link to [dcl.init.general], I find 14 where I read that

The initialization that occurs in […] throwing an exception ([except.throw]), handling an exception ([except.handle]) […] is called copy-initialization.

But I don't really understand how that tells me about the slicing.
In my example, e1 has a static type (std::exception) and a dynamic type (std::runtime_error), right? So I don't know exactly how to read §14.4 as regards the types E and T mentioned there.

A side, non-language-lawyer quesion is: why is the behavrior as it is? Is it a design choice? Or a design necessity?

What you throw is base class subobject, you can not throw references so copy is made of that base class subobject. Same would be if you pass base class subobject to function that accepts stuff by value.

@RichardCritten throw; only works when you are currently handling an exception (i.e., you are in catch body). Here e1 is just an  exception object passed around, it's not being handled.

As to the necessity, The exception object being thrown has to live somewhere other than the stack that is about to be unwound. So the implementation can't just take a reference to whatever is past to throw, it must make a copy. It would be a pretty big burden otherwise.

Also, the standard doesn't have to bother to warn about slicing everywhere. Slicing ALWAYS occurs when a derived object is copied into a baseclass object, regardless of context. And while I don't know whether the C++ standard even mentions slicing, it's completely unnecessary to do that since it's super-obvious: when you copy a derived-class object into a base-class object, you get a base-class object as result. What else would you get? C++ does very little in terms of hidden magic.

First, note that there is an object controlled by the implementation and not explicit in the source:
[except.throw/3]

Throwing an exception initializes an object with dynamic storage duration, called the exception object. If the type of the exception object would be an incomplete type ([basic.types.general]), an abstract class type ([class.abstract]), or a pointer to an incomplete type other than cv void ([basic.compound]) the program is ill-formed.

This exception object will be initialized by the throw expression throw e1 and it is the object to which the handler will bind. For this reason, you should not expect three copies of the same address in your example here. The first two are addresses for the object passed to throw, and the third is an address for the exception object. And these are going to be different because these are different objects.
What is the type of the exception object?
[expr.throw/2]

A throw-expression with an operand throws an exception ([except.throw]). The array-to-pointer ([conv.array]) and function-to-pointer ([conv.func]) standard conversions are performed on the operand. The type of the exception object is determined by removing any top-level cv-qualifiers from the type of the (possibly converted) operand. The exception object is copy-initialized ([dcl.init.general]) from the (possibly converted) operand.

The type of the expression e1 (the operand of the throw expression) is const std::exception. The rules are here, but expressions never have reference type. This is what you would get from:
std::remove_reference_t<decltype((e1))>

You have to add parentheses around a name to get the type of the expression, and decltype adds a reference depending on the value category, which you must remove if you only want the type of the expression.
So... the operand has type const std::exception. We check array-to-pointer and function-to-pointer conversions, and neither apply. So the type of the exception object is determined by removing any top-level cv-qualifiers. Thus, the type of the exception object is std::exception.
The object of type std::exception is copy-initialized from the operand. Therefore, it is as if we had written:
std::exception exception_object = e1;

That we are copy-initializing is not the relevant part of the paragraph. The type of the object we are initializing is the relevant part.

the second line, if I understand correctly, is not mandated by the standard

The string returned by std::exception::what() is implementation-defined.

In my example, e1 has a static type (std::exception) and a dynamic type (std::runtime_error), right? So I don't know exactly how to read §14.4 as regards the types E and T mentioned there.

E is the type of the exception object which has static and dynamic type std::exception.

A side, non-language-lawyer quesion is: why is the behavrior as it is? Is it a design choice? Or a design necessity?

As I noted in a comment, the reason this is natural is that there needs to be an object "on the side", not on the stack, because we are unwinding. The way in C++ we create a new object from an existing one is to copy.

My expectation was initially (before even formulating the question) that the 3 addresses would have been the same. But thanks, I understand now that the main think I missed is Throwing an exception initializes an object, so the exception object can't be a reference to the operand of throw because a reference would not the an object in the first place. Thanks!

The slicing happens when you throw the exception https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.throw#2

The type of the exception object is determined by removing any top-level cv-qualifiers from the type of the (possibly converted) operand.
The exception object is copy-initialized from the (possibly converted) operand.

It's as if you do throw std::decay_t<decltype(e1)>(e1);
This is necessary since a new object needs to be constructed wherever the exception object is stored, so it can only allocate however many bytes for the declared type of the object and can only call the move constructor of the declared type of the object (how would it know to call runtime_error's move constructor?)

The text you quoted is the paragraph from which I quoted a sentence, so I've read that. And I know what "removing any top-level cv-qualifiers from the type" means, but that only justifies the std::remove_cv part of std::decay. What about the std::remove_reference part of it? Is it "object is copy-initialized" that implies it?

@Enlico Expressions can't have reference type, decltype(e1) could be a reference type

Yes, but if I was passing the expression e1 to a function accepting std::exception const& e2, name e2 in that function would still be referring to the same object e1 referred to. That is not what happens in the snippet in my question, with catch "playing the role of the function". Or, putting it in terms of code, why don't I read 3 times the same address here?

@Enlico "The type of the exception object is determined by removing any top-level cv qualifiers from the type of the operand." The type of the operand is std::exception (no reference, because the type of an expression is never a reference). When initializing a function argument, the type as well as the value category of the expression is considered.

Also, with catch "playing the role of the function": catch is binding a reference to the exception object, but the exception object is a copy of the object passed to throw, so you wouldn't expect the address to equal.
